cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils' (/Users/aneeshnagarajan/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py)
I was trying to import
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE 

but I get this error
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils' (/Users//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py)

how can i solve this

maybe it needs older of sklearn.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Without more information about the error message you are receiving, it's difficult to provide a specific solution. Have you installed imblearn, you can install it using pip: pip install imblearn.

python - cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' - Stack Overflow

I checked source code for sklearn and I found parse_version in sklearn.utils.fixes . Probably imblearn was created for older sklearn and you may have to try to install different older versions until you find working version. Maybe imblearn has file requirements.txt with information what modules and versions it needs to work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please provide packages versions pip show imblearn and pip show  scikit-learn. Cheers.

I got the similar issue. I checked my imblanaced-learn and scikit-learn versions before and after I upgrade the environment. After upgrading, my code can't work.
Before and after: imbalanced learn version 0.11.0
Before: scikit-learn version 1.3.2
After: scikit-learn version 1.5.1
It is clear that currently imbalanced learn 0.11.0 version doesn't support scikit-learn 1.5.1.
scikit-learn 1.5.1 uses
from sklearn.utils.fixes import parse_version
You can see the updates here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/commit/4c35c0f9f6b3e882927e2e0f1f07ee403d122f11
